# Inheriting classes from gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, rubygems

I installed a gem called `line-bot-api` which is a bot sdk for LINE (a messaging app). I would like to extend the class defined in the gem and use it in rails.

What is the right way to do this? What I've tried so far is to create a `line_client.rb` under `lib` with the following content.

```
class LineClient < Line::Bot::Client

  def initialize
    @client ||= Line::Bot::Client.new { |config|
      config.channel_secret = ENV["LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET"]
      config.channel_token = ENV["LINE_CHANNEL_TOKEN"]
    }
  end

end
```

However, I get an `uninitialized constant Line` error.

Comment: `require 'line/bot'` missing at the top of the file?

Comment: Also if you're just creating a proxy class, then you should not derive `LineClient` from `Line::Bot::Client`. Just `class LineClient` will do.